# Como pasar datos de string a list para volcarlos en excel?

Tags: python, excel, lista

estoy scrapeando unos links y volcando el contenido en un excel. Todo va bien hasta que intento escribir el excel con openpyxl, ahi recibo el error:

> TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>

```
El código es:

    #---------------------FUNCION SCRAPEO----------------------

def scrapeo (lista):
  precios = []
  for i in lista:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    browser.get(i)
    #Incorporo BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    #Extraigo la pagina principal y convierto a str
    pagina_principal_bs4 = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-sm-5 col-xs-7 precio'})
    pagina=str(pagina_principal_bs4)
    pagina = " ".join(pagina.split())
##    print(pagina)
    def cleanhtml(pagina): 
      cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
      cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '\n', pagina)
      return cleantext
    texto= cleanhtml(pagina).replace("\n", "").split(",")
##    print(texto)
    precio = texto[0].split(" ")
##    precio = precio[3]
    precios.append(precio)
  return(precios)

#--------------Lista precios completa------

precios = []

#-----------Analgesicos 1--------------------

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\rbisa\OneDrive - ECOGO S.A\BD\Precios\RPM Estudio Bein\Alimentos Scrapping\Base scrapping varios.xlsx', sheet_name='Salud')
subset = data[data.Fuente == "Analgésicos"]
links= subset.loc [:, 'link']

descartables=[]
for i in links:
  descartables.append(i)

precios_descartables =scrapeo(descartables)
precios_descartables = [element[0].replace("$","").replace("[","").replace("]","") for element in precios_descartables]  

Analgesicos = [s.replace('$', '') for s in precios_descartables]

for i in Analgesicos:
    precios.append(i)

print(type(precios)) #Me devuelve que es una lista
print(precios)

wb = load_workbook(r"path")
ws = wb.worksheets[7]

for i in precios:
  ws.append(i)
  
wb.save("path")
```

Sospecho que el problema es que se convierte en string cuando lo pongo en:

```
    for i in precios:
  ws.append(i)
```

pero no se como agregarlo sin declarar cada uno de los items de la lista como una variable. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

En tu código `precios` es una **lista de strings**, con lo que al recorrer la lista obtienes varios strings.

```
precios= ['123', '256', '378', '412']
```

Como **update** exige una **lista de datos** no es una opción válida.

```
[ws.append([precio]) for precio in precios]
```

Al poner `precio` entre corchetes ya los tienes en una lista.

Estos precios pasan a la hoja de cálculo como **str** y los puedes querer en un tipo **float** con lo que quedaría así:

```
[ws.append([float(precio)]) for precio in precios]
```

Comment: lo correcto sería `hoja = [[precio] for precio in precios]` y lo mismo para el woorkbook `ws = [[float(precio)] for precio in precios]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la apreciación @Christian, un placer aprender de ellas. Como mi código funciona me atreví a subirlo. El tuyo supera mis conocimientos y no soy a implementarlo. Seguiré intentándolo.

Comment: Eee.... mi código no te funciona? No soy experto en openpyxl por lo que puede que talvez haya ignorado un pequeño detalle, pero dada la sintaxis que usas solo la transformé al uso normal de una comprensión de lista (ya que lo que haces es una comprensión de lista pero "mal"). Igual puedes seguir investigando y experimentando, animos!  :D